# Автообновление отключили?

Tags: поддержка

Над лентой больше не появляется плашка с уведомлением о новых вопросах и в процессе написания ответа не появляются в режиме реального времени ответы от других участников.

Comment: У меня работает по старому.

Comment: @Андрей, как это работает? о_О Ты точно на главной находишься?

Comment: Ой.. Тьфу... Надо было внимательнее вопрос читать...

Comment: @Qwertiy, хз как на новой главной, но вот, например, по метке: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfxZJ.png